# AngularJS & SEOing

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm working on a small Angular application, and I'm about midway through with a mind breaking issue. It's common knowledge that SEO spiders/crawlers tend to not use Javascript, hence all META data must be loaded during server load. I'm trying to create a very dynamic base, that I can reuse for future projects.

My application is being built using LAMP, I'm not against Node but I must use PHP/MySQL for this particular project. I have a main configuration document 'config.json', and via the main index page I'm loading it in before HTML rendering to set all important META data. Now, I'm then loading the **same** configuration file in my Angular application using 'http.get(...)'. I just feel as if there's absolutely no need to load the same file twice.

I can solve this issue by setting the configuration via a script on the main page like so,

```
<?php

   $config_plain = file_get_contents( './app/data/config.json', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH );
   $config = json_decode( $config_plain );
       // #    set config for meta data on load

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="foobar" ng-controller="dataCtrl">
   <head>
      <title ng-bind="page.title"><?php echo $config->title; ?></title>
      <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $config->meta->description; ?>">
      ...
      <script>
         angular.module('foobar', [...])
            .controller('dataCtrl', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
               $rootScope.config = <?php echo $config_plain; ?>;
                  $rootScope.page = {  };
                  $rootScope.page.title = $rootScope.config.brand;

                    //    # set config for data binding
            }])

            .service('page', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
                return {
                    title: function(route) {
                        $rootScope.page.title = $rootScope.config.brand + ' | ' + route;
                            // #    update page title dynamically
                    }
                };
            }]);
      </script>
   </head>
</html>
```

Which would alternatively be,

```
<?php

   $config_plain = file_get_contents( './app/data/config.json', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH );
   $config = json_decode( $config_plain );
       // #    set config for meta data on load

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="foobar" ng-controller="dataCtrl">
   <head>
      <title ng-bind="page.title"><?php echo $config->title; ?></title>
      <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $config->meta->description; ?>">
      ...
      <script>
         angular.module('foobar', [...])
            .controller('dataCtrl', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
               $http.get('/app/data/config.json')
                  .success(function(response) {
                      $rootScope.config = response;
                          $rootScope.page = {  };
                          $rootScope.page.title = $rootScope.config.brand;
                            // #    set config for data binding
                   });
            }])

            .service('page', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
                return {
                    title: function(route) {
                        $rootScope.page.title = $rootScope.config.brand + ' | ' + route;
                            // #    update page title dynamically
                    }
                };
            }]);
      </script>
   </head>
</html>
```

Though this all kind of seems really messy.

My actual question is, how would I go about SEOing application content dynamically using both angular and php?

Comment: google has well documented guidelines for ajax driven pages as well as mentions a variety of solutions

Answer (score 0):

Almost four years ago Matt Cutts said:

> Googlebot keeps getting smarter. Now has the ability to execute AJAX/JS > to index some dynamic comments http://goo.gl/F9et1

Here is google's official blogpost if you have detailed questions. http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/11/get-post-and-safely-surfacing-more-of.html

I honestly think you'll be fine. Test it. Tweet your experiment page, so that the page gets indexed and go from there. As for the other search engines (Yahoo and Bing) I think they won't be able to do this for a while, if ever.

Note: MC's comments were about JS based comments not entire pages but I can't find the link of G's others developments to understanding JS. I know it's much more advanced now.